# Powershell "join"

Tags: powershell, join

Call me stupid, but I'm losing my hair with this one.

I have two results from a Get-WmiObject:

```
$cpu = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor 
$mb = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BaseBoard
```

Now, I can filter and output a CSV file from each one:

```
$cpu | Select-Object Name, Description | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

and

```
$mb | Select-Object Manufacturer, Product | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But... How the hell could I **join** these two outputs and make a single CSV output from both? Something like:

```
( 
  ($cpu | Select-Object Name, Description) + 
  ($mb | Select-Object Manufacturer, Product) 
) | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

(of course, this syntax is invalid. Just to show the point)

Answer (score 12):

You need Powershell V2 for the following.

```
$cpu = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor 
$mb = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BaseBoard
$props = @{            
    Name          = $cpu.Name
    Description   = $cpu.Description
    Manufacturer  = $mb.Manufacturer
    Product       = $mb.Product
    }
New-Object PSObject -Property $props | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: While this works perfectly for OPs question, those coming here looking for joining multiple rows of data will have to pursue an alternative strategy.

Comment: @KyleMit, `Select-Object` with calculated properties might be useful to you.

Answer (score 5):

There's a `Join-Object` [function on PoshCode](http://poshcode.org/1461) for doing this, but it's buried inside `Join-Collection` and not exported.

```
 function Join-Object {
    Param(
       [Parameter(Position=0)]
       $First
    ,
       [Parameter(Position=1,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
       $Second
    )
    BEGIN {
       [string[]] $p1 = $First | gm -type Properties | select -expand Name
    }
    Process {
       $Output = $First | Select $p1
       foreach($p in $Second | gm -type Properties | Where { $p1 -notcontains $_.Name } | select -expand Name) {
          Add-Member -in $Output -type NoteProperty -name $p -value $Second."$p"
       }
       $Output
    }
 }
```

Once you've defined that, you can use it like this:

```
Join-Object (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor) (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BaseBoard) | 
Select Name, Description, Manufacturer, Product
```

Or keep your variables, and do it like:

```
$cpu = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor 
$mb = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BaseBoard

Join-Object $cpu $mb  | Select Name, Description, Manufacturer, Product
```

Answer (score 1):

How about like this?

```
echo $cpu $mb | Select-Object Name, Description, Manufacturer, Product | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Almost! This actually returns four columns, but in *TWO* lines. Each line containing two values and two nulls. Now, if we could make a kind of "union"...

Comment: There is `-join "a","b"`, I am trying to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add whatever properties you need to a custom powershell object that has what you need and then dump the cvs.  Take a look at this [page](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/pstips/apr08/pstip0411.mspx) and see if it suites what you need.

Comment: There is, in PowerShell 2, see the example by @dangph

Answer (score 0):

You can start with either object and then add properties from the other:

```
$cpu | Select-Object Name, Description | 
  add-member noteproperty Manufacturer $mb.Manufacturer -PassThru | 
  add-member noteproperty Product      $mb.Product      -PassThru
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
Somewhat longer then I expected, because both $cpu and $mb have Name and Manufacturer properties. But the prime idea is the custom objects through hashing.

```
($cpu | Select-Object Name, Description),($mb | Select-Object Manufacturer, Product) | 
       Select-Object @{name='NameOrManu';expr={$_.Name + $_.Manufacturer}},  
                     @{name='DescrOrProd';expr={$_.Description + $_.Product}} | 
       ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join), described in [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026) has a lot more capabilities, but can also be used like this:

```
$cpu | Select-Object Name, Description | Join-Object ($mb | Select-Object Manufacturer, Product)
```